# Populate a deeply nested object based on values from a reference object

Tags: javascript, object, data-structures, merge, nested

this is my first SO question, so if i've messed something up or missed a detail/ used wrong terminology, please let me know :)

I've been banging my head trying to find a way to populate a deeply nested Array of objects (data) by looking up all values stored in keys called 'code', on another dictionary-like reference object (dict).

**A note:**
My actual use case for this is receiving user settings from a DB, and populating with client-side presentation data (like labels for checkboxes). I want to reduce the data the server must send to the client, and I believe just codes and settings values are enough. The reference object would be loaded once and cached. For all I know, the costs that I will be saving are so minimal that it doesn't warrant this kind of cumbersome object processing. If this is the case, please let me know. Additionally, if there are actual practices on how this kind of use case is done, please also let me know, I would be very appreciative! :)

So, my two data structures look like this:

```
// The first is deeply nested, and all 'code' keys need to be found.
const data = [
  {
    // Other data irrelevant to the question...
    level_1: [
      {
        code: 9111,
        level_2: [
          {
            code: 111,
            // more irrelevant data
          },
          {code: 112},
        ],
      },
      {
        code: 9112,
        level_2: [
          {code: 113},
          {code: 114},
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    level_1: [
      {
        code: 9112,
        level_2: [
          {code: 115},
          {code: 116},
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]

// The second is a simple object with code values as keys, and some text as values

const dict = {
   9111: "yet another string",
   111: "some string",
   ...
   112: "some other string",
}
```

My goal is to return a copy of obj1 (not mutate obj1), but with additional keys called 'text', which hold the relevant string from the reference object.

Example returned object:

```
{
  level_1: [
    {
      code: 9111,
      text: "yet another string", // THIS HAS BEEN ADDED BASED ON REF OBJECT
      level_2: [
        {
          code: 111,
          text: "some string" // THIS HAS BEEN ADDED BASED ON REF OBJECT
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So far, I've tried using nested .forEach(), then read that its very bad practice to nest them (though still not sure why, likely performance). Then I tried using .map(), but that resulted in too much complexity in code which i couldnt get my head around.

Using something from lodash or the like is not an issue.

Any help is truly appreciated, and thank you all in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your attempts. Thanks.

Comment: _"then read that its very bad practice to nest them"_ Where have you read it? Don't believe everything you read somewhere. _"I've tried using nested .forEach() ... Then I tried using .map()"_ Show your attempts.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: If you're just trying to copy your object before it's mutated you should use object.assign.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign